# checking for xpath selector in rails using capybara

Tags: xpath, capybara

I am checking a label with text like

> user's email can't be blank

I am testing it as follow:

```
 assert_selector(:xpath,"//label[text()[contains(.,'user''s email can''t be blank')]]")
```

but it is not working.

Also I tried this:

```
assert_selector(:xpath,"//label[text()[contains(.,'user\'s email can\'t be blank')]]")
```

Can some please tell me how to check for selector?

Answer (score 1):

How about you reverse the quotes:

```
assert_selector(:xpath, '//label[contains(., "user\'s email can\'t be blank")]')
```